# How to Monitor Incoming SMS in Android API <19 & API >=19?

Tags: android, android-sms

Am try to Monitoring Incoming SMS in my App. From Android Side they done some change for Monitoring incoming SMS from **API 19**.

Can't Track incoming Message in Background(at the time of App not in Background & Mobile Screen in Off State) in **API 23**.

In Android Document said Can't Track Incoming SMS in Background if your app is not as a Default Message App From **API 19**.

Ref:- [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

But its working on My **API 21(LOLLIPOP)** device. It will not working on **API 23(Marshmallow)** devices. When Devices Screen is on or the app is open means it Working in **API 23(Marshmallow)** also.

Can You Please Update Me Is there any Way to Track Incoming Message in Background in **API 23(Marshmallow)**.

**Manifest Code**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<receiver
        android:name=".SMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="5822">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Here My Java Code**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String BROADCAST = "SMS_RECEIVER";
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

Intent broadcast_intent;
String message_body = "", originAddress;

StringBuilder bodyText;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(SMS_RECEIVED)) {

        broadcast_intent = new Intent(BROADCAST);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages;

        if (bundle != null) {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            bodyText = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    String format = bundle.getString("format");
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
                } else {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }

                originAddress = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress().toUpperCase();
                bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());

            }

            message_body = bodyText.toString();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of introducing Android 6.0 (API 23) Google made a huge change in app permission technique.So for API >=23 users needs to grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app

**System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous:**

1. **Normal permissions** do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically.
2. **Dangerous permissions** can give the app access to the user's confidential data. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically. If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give approval to your app.

Permission for Accessing the phones sms manager is considered as **Dangerous Permission** and that's why it needs to be called programmatically inside your code where you are trying to use phones smsmanager.

You can request permission in your mainActivity like this

```
int hasSMSPermission = checkSelfPermission( Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS );
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();

if( hasSMSPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
    permissions.add( Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS );
}

if( !permissions.isEmpty() ) {
    requestPermissions( permissions.toArray( new String[permissions.size()] ), REQUEST_CODE_SOME_FEATURES_PERMISSIONS );
}
```

And to receive the request result of permission and set up your brodcast receiver make an override method of onActivityResult like this:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch ( requestCode ) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SOME_FEATURES_PERMISSIONS: {
            for( int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++ ) {
                if( grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    Log.d( "Permissions", "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i] );
                } else if( grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ) {
                    Log.d( "Permissions", "Permission Denied: " + permissions[i] );
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        default: {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

see this link for more details : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Am done all the Security Permission Check. For the Permission Where i Used.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can register a broadcast receiver to listen for `SMS_Receive` and check out the following.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("mySMS");

if (bundle != null) {
    Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[0]);
    Log.i(TAG, "smsActivity : SMS is <" +  sms.getMessageBody() +">");


    String message = sms.getMessageBody();
    //required sms
    TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextBox);
    tx.setText(message);            
} else
    Log.i(TAG, "smsActivity : NULL SMS bundle");
```

Comment: is "SMS_Receive" or "android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" considered dangerous? can i use it without being the default SMS app?